# Selenium html webdriver Unable to locate element

Tags: java, html, selenium

I tried looking around for this error, but most of the time the problem was spelling errors, and I triple checked my spelling.
So here is the problem. I want to navigate around a website. I have this as my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("hgta_doFilterPage"));
element.submit();
WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.name("hgta_fil.v.hg19.refGene.name.pat"));
filter.sendKeys("");
```

I am trying to go to the website listed, go down to the 'filter' page section, click create and then enter some values on the next page in the 'name' section and then submit again. 
But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: hgta_fil.v.hg19.refGene.name.pat
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.37.1', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-21 09:08:07'
System info: host: 'OSXLAP00693.local', ip: '192.168.2.9', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
```

I double checked the naming on the page: `view-source:http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables`
and found:

```
<TR VALIGN=BOTTOM align='left'><TD colspan=2> name </TD><TD>
<SELECT NAME='hgta_fil.v.hg19.knownGene.name.dd' class='normalText' style='width: 76px' >
<OPTION SELECTED>does</OPTION>
<OPTION>doesn't</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</TD><TD>match </TD><TD>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT class='inputBox' NAME="hgta_fil.v.hg19.knownGene.name.pat" style='width: 140px' VALUE="*">
&nbsp; </TD></TR>
<TR VALIGN=BOTTOM align='left'><TD colspan=2> chrom </TD><TD>
<SELECT NAME='hgta_fil.v.hg19.knownGene.chrom.dd' class='normalText' style='width: 76px' ><!-- Here -->
<OPTION SELECTED>does</OPTION>
<OPTION>doesn't</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</TD><TD>match </TD><TD>
```

I am wondering if I am having this problem because the web driver is no longer pointing at the correct site?

Comment: Hey Stephopolis, it might help if you used a framework that can help you get started.  check out http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium . it'll help you get started and show you the ropes with selenium and also simplifies things like crazy.  I use a version of this framework where I work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input box in the source has the name `hgta_fil.v.hg19.knownGene.name.pat`, but you are searching for an element with name `hgta_fil.v.hg19.refGene.name.pat`.

Comment: I sort of thought that it would be the case, but because this is my first time, I haven't had too much experience with it. Is there a way to grab the new contents? When I said driver.get("") I was telling the driver what to do, but can I get that information from the page somehow?

Comment: Wait, I've misunderstood the problem. See if this is the issue.